# ctypes.cast works in python2 and throws ArgumentError in python3

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I'm having an issue where my ctypes code works in python2 but fails in python3.

The function I'm failing in is arrptr_to_np, which is trying to take an array created in an external c library and load it into a numpy array.

The function looks like this

```
def arrptr_to_np(c_arrptr, shape, arr_t, dtype):
    """
    Casts an array pointer from C to numpy

    Args:
        c_arrpt (uint64): a pointer to an array returned from C
        shape (tuple): shape of the underlying array being pointed to
        arr_t (PyCSimpleType): the ctypes datatype of c_arrptr
        dtype (dtype): numpy datatype the array will be to cast into
    """ 
    byte_t = ctypes.c_char
    itemsize_ = dtype().itemsize
    dtype_t = byte_t * itemsize_
    dtype_ptr_t = C.POINTER(dtype_t)  # size of each item
    typed_c_arrptr = c_arrptr.astype(int)
    c_arr = C.cast(typed_c_arrptr, dtype_ptr_t)   # cast to ctypes
    np_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(c_arr, shape)
    np_arr.dtype = dtype
    return np_arr
```

These are the values of the variables in the example I'm working with

varname  - value - type(var)

c_arrptr - 20622304 - numpy.uint64

shape    - (506, 6) - tuple

arr_t   -  numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer_< f4_2d_ALIGNED_C_CONTIGUOUS_WRITEABLE - _ctypes.PyCSimpleType

dtype - np.float32 - np.float32

These are the same between python2 and python3 versions (except the value of the pointer of course, but it is still uint64)

When I execute the function it works as expected in python2. 
However, in python3 I get an error on this line

```
c_arr = C.cast(typed_c_arrptr, dtype_ptr_t)   # cast to ctypes
```

The error is an ArgumentError

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py in cast(obj, typ)
    487 def cast(obj, typ):
--> 488     return _cast(obj, obj, typ)
    489 

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
in <module>()
----> 1 c_arr = C.cast(typed_c_arrptr, dtype_ptr_t)   # cast to ctypes

/usr/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py in cast(obj, typ)
    486 _cast = PYFUNCTYPE(py_object, c_void_p, py_object, py_object)(_cast_addr)
    487 def cast(obj, typ):
--> 488     return _cast(obj, obj, typ)
    489 
    490 _string_at = PYFUNCTYPE(py_object, c_void_p, c_int)(_string_at_addr)

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

At that point in the code execution typed_c_arrptr is a dtype('int64') in both versions of the program. dtype_ptr_t is a LP_c_char_Array_4
 also in both versions.

I've tried many variations on typed_c_arrptr = c_arrptr.astype(int) replacing int with ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_size_t. At this point I'm just guessing as to what to do and what is going wrong. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you replace `int` with `long` in each version?

Comment: long doesn't exist as a keyword in python3, in python 2 it does not work. I tried using ctypes.c_long as well.

Comment: I don't have Python 3, but as far as I know `int` is a different size compared to Python 2. `long` has a different size to `int` within Python 2, and that is also causing your code to fail it seems. Might be a hint.

Comment: I'm aware of that difference, but it does not seem to be the issue. Perhaps it should be changes to ctypes.c_int32 or something similar, but even when that happens the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The error tell you, that the first argument couldn't be converted to `ctypes.c_void_p`. That is `typed_c_arrptr` couldn't be converted.

This happens, because `astype()` works differently int both versions of Python. With Python 3 you have

```
>>> isinstance(np.uint64(12345).astype(int), int)
False
```

and therefore ctypes doesn't know how to convert `np.uint64`. Whereas with Python 2 you have

```
>>> isinstance(np.uint64(12345).astype(int), int)
True
```

so ctypes just treats it as if it was an `int`.

Further [the documentation of `generic.astype()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.generic.astype.html#numpy.generic.astype) reads

> Not implemented (virtual attribute)
>
> Class generic exists solely to derive numpy scalars from, and possesses, albeit unimplemented, all the attributes of the ndarray class so as to provide a uniform API.

and I have no idea, why it works with Python 2.

Instead you could just use `int()` to convert the `np.uint64` to something that could be cast to `ctypes.c_void_p`. This worked for me with both versions.

```
c_arr = C.cast(int(c_arrptr), dtype_ptr_t)
```